# Change Time.now timezone rails minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to make a test work regardless of the server's timezone.
There is a function that was called in the module I'm creating the test for which is:

Time.now().iso8601.to_s

I am able to stub the date and time properly however, I am currently on a GMT+8 timezone which makes the result of the above function:

2021-07-19T01:00:00+08:00

But upon deploying it in azure server, it becomes

2021-07-19T01:00:00-05:00

How can I get this test passing regardless of the server's timezone?

Answer (score 0):

you could stub method `:iso8601` to return a fake time for all instance of `Time`, then in all of your expectations which relative to the time, you should expect to equal the `fake_time`.

minitest

```rb
require "test_helper"
require "minitest/mock"
class StubTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def freeze_time(fixed_time=Time.now, &block)
    Time.stub(:now,fixed_time) do
      fixed_time.stub(:iso8601, fixed_time) do
        block.call
      end  
    end
  end

  test "stub time" do
   freeze_time(stub_time=Time.new(2021)) do
     assert_equal Time.now.iso8601, stub_time
     task = # create task
     assert_equal task.deadline_at, stub_time
   end
  end
end
```

better approach (in my opinion), you'll run test code in a fixed time-zone block, reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/test/time_zone_test_helpers.rb

```rb
class StubTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def with_env_tz(new_tz = "US/Eastern")
    old_tz, ENV["TZ"] = ENV["TZ"], new_tz
    yield
  ensure
    old_tz ? ENV["TZ"] = old_tz : ENV.delete("TZ")
  end

  test "stub time zone" do
    # support your code run on server in time-zone US/Eastern
    # Time.zone == 'US/Eastern' 
    out = Time.zone.now.iso8601

    # now you force in time-zone Europe/Athens
    with_env_tz "Europe/Athens" do
      assert_equal Time.now.iso8601, out # FAILED
    end
  end
end
```

so you could wrap all your test codes relative to time-zone inside a block run in fixed time-zone.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.now` gives the time in System timezone. That is the system current timezone which is different for the server and your device.

What you want to use is `Time.zone.now` or `Time.current` which will return the time in Application timezone.

```rb
Time.current.iso8601.to_s
```

You can also set the the application timezone in `config/application.rb` which is UTC by default.

`config.time_zone = "UTC"`

Run `Time.zone.name` in rails console to find out the current application timezone.